# Create new data frame based on values from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Data frame looks like this:

```
id pom.1 pom.2 pom.3 pom.4 pom.5 pom.6 pom.7 pom.8
20764422   1   3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
08049335   4   2   1   5   8   7   9   3
07668511   5   2   7  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
20058102   7   4   2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
17318802   6   3   5   1   9   8   2  <NA>
```

where there is the list of 10 possible values that can be found in this data frame.

I need to create another dataframe which will have 10 columns, one for each value from the list and match it with original data frame.

New data frame should look like this:

```
id c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
20764422 y n y n n n n n n n
08049335 y y y y y n y y y n
07668511 n y n n y n y n n n
20058102 n y n y n n y n n n
17318802 y y y n y y n y y n
```

where each row (c1-c10) should match with one value from the list of values. Values "y" and "n" for each id mean that some value is/isn't present in original data frame.

Hopefully this exlanation is good enough to understand what needs to be done.

I tried to find an answer before posting, but either there was no answer or my search wasn't good enough. Anyway, sorry if I posted with answer already available here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `ifelse(is.na(YourDataFrame),'n','y')`

Comment: Patrick, thanks for fast reply, but I think you didnt understand my question (or my explanation wasn't good enough). There are 8 columns in original df which can have values 1-10. I want to create new df with 10 colums (one for each value 1-10) and put "y" or "n" depending on if row has that value in original df or not.

Comment: Please explain more clearly when a `y` should be assigned to a certain `c` column. As it is described now, it is not clear how the expected output should be derived. For example, you should specify the list of 10 possible values.

Comment: Jaap, I hope my previous comment explains more clearly what I want.

Comment: Ok, now I got that you want to get the occurrence of the numbers 1 to 10 in each row. See my answer below. BTW: A smaller example would make the problem easier to understand.

Comment: @AnandaMahto your answer works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can live with a binary 1 and 0 instead of a "y" and "n", you can try something like the following.

It helps if you provide a reproducible (`dput`) or your data so that we know whether you're dealing with numeric, character, or factor variables.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(as.data.table(mydf), "id"), id ~ value)
# Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
#          id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 NA
# 1:  7668511 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0  5
# 2:  8049335 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1  0
# 3: 17318802 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1  1
# 4: 20058102 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0  5
# 5: 20764422 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  6
```

If you really want to, you can do something like this:

```
dcast(melt(as.data.table(mydf), "id", na.rm = TRUE)[          ## melt and remove NA
      , value := factor(value, 1:10)],                        ## factor value column 
      id ~ value,                                             ## pivot value by id
      fun.aggregate = function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), "n", "y"), ## get your "y" and "n"
      fill = "n", drop = FALSE)                               ## don't drop missing factors
```

Which yields:

```
##          id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
## 1: 07668511 n y n n y n y n n  n
## 2: 08049335 y y y y y n y y y  n
## 3: 17318802 y y y n y y n y y  n
## 4: 20058102 n y n y n n y n n  n
## 5: 20764422 y n y n n n n n n  n
```

---

#### Update

Here's a "for fun" answer using `tabulate` and `chartr`:

```
temp <- `rownames<-`(t(apply(mydf[-1], 1, function(x) tabulate(x, nbins = 10))), mydf[[1]])
temp[] <- chartr("01", "ny", temp)
temp
#          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# 20764422 "y"  "n"  "y"  "n"  "n"  "n"  "n"  "n"  "n"  "n"  
# 08049335 "y"  "y"  "y"  "y"  "y"  "n"  "y"  "y"  "y"  "n"  
# 07668511 "n"  "y"  "n"  "n"  "y"  "n"  "y"  "n"  "n"  "n"  
# 20058102 "n"  "y"  "n"  "y"  "n"  "n"  "y"  "n"  "n"  "n"  
# 17318802 "y"  "y"  "y"  "n"  "y"  "y"  "n"  "y"  "y"  "n"
```

---

Sample data used in this answer (not necessarily what you have):

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = c("20764422", "08049335", "07668511", "20058102", 
    "17318802"), pom.1 = c(1L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L), pom.2 = c(3L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 3L), pom.3 = c(NA, 1L, 7L, 2L, 5L), pom.4 = c(NA, 5L, 
    NA, NA, 1L), pom.5 = c(NA, 8L, NA, NA, 9L), pom.6 = c(NA, 7L, 
    NA, NA, 8L), pom.7 = c(NA, 9L, NA, NA, 2L), pom.8 = c(NA, 3L, 
    NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("id", "pom.1", "pom.2", "pom.3", "pom.4", 
    "pom.5", "pom.6", "pom.7", "pom.8"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you don't want to use any package and want to stick to basic data.frame, you could do this pretty basically :

```
# Creating some data that looks like yours
> df <- data.frame(matrix(c(101:105,sample(c(1:10,NA),40,replace=T)),5,9,dimnames=list(x=NULL,y=c("id",sapply(1:8,function(x) paste("pom",x))))))
> print(df)
   id pom.1 pom.2 pom.3 pom.4 pom.5 pom.6 pom.7 pom.8
1 101     2    NA     7    NA     5     1    NA     2
2 102     7     4     8     2     1     5    NA     4
3 103     6     8     5     2     9     8     2     7
4 104     9    NA     4     5     3     9     7     9
5 105     1     7     6     2     3     4     5     5
# Creating the output
> ndf <- t(apply(df,1,function(l) sapply(1:10,function(x) ifelse(x %in% l, 'y', 'n'))))
> dimnames(ndf) <- list(as.character(101:105),as.character(1:10))
> print(ndf)
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
101 "y" "y" "n" "n" "y" "n" "y" "n" "n" "n"
102 "y" "y" "n" "y" "y" "n" "y" "y" "n" "n"
103 "n" "y" "n" "n" "y" "y" "y" "y" "y" "n"
104 "n" "n" "y" "y" "y" "n" "y" "n" "y" "n"
105 "y" "y" "y" "y" "y" "y" "y" "n" "n" "n"
```

Note that I wouldn't recommend this solution for large datasets. @Ananda Mahto's solutions are probably the most optimal.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(dfN[1], mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(dfN[-1]))))
```

---

Or using `table` from `base R`.  We `unlist` the columns of the dataset except the 'id' column, get the `table` of 'id' column ( replicated to make the lengths same) and the `unlist`ed columns, change the logical index to numeric, replace the values by 'n', 'y' and `cbind` with the 'id' column.

```
tbl <- !!table(dfN$id[row(dfN[-1])], factor(unlist(dfN[-1]), levels=1:10))
tbl[] <- c('n', 'y')[tbl+1L]
`row.names<-`(cbind(dfN[1], as.data.frame.matrix(tbl)), NULL)
#         id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#1 20764422 n y n n y n y n n  n
#2  8049335 y y y y y n y y y  n
#3  7668511 y y y n y y n y y  n
#4 20058102 n y n y n n y n n  n
#5 17318802 y n y n n n n n n  n
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution in base R using `apply` over a matrix (using a smaller example):

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, NA, 3), col2 = c(2, 10, NA))

as.data.frame(ifelse(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) (1:10) %in% x[!is.na(x)])), 
                     'y', 'n'))

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  y  y  n  n  n  n  n  n  n   n
2  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n   y
3  n  n  y  n  n  n  n  n  n   n
```

You probably will have to adapt the rownames and colnames finally.